# Integrating google drive with a 2.1+ android application

Tags: android, google-drive-api, synchronization, android-version

I'm trying to have my apps sync their database with drive so that the app data is n'sync throughout all his devices. I did some research and found this quickstart, [Dr.Edit](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/android) but when I downloaded the source code for a closer inspection I realised it's for 4.1+. Surprised, I checked the [google drive app on google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs&hl=es) and found out you can install it on 2.1+.

I understand that later versions of android OS not only work better but make our work as developer easier. However I am surprised I cannot find much about integrating google drive with older versions. If we check the [current distribution of android versions](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), we can easily notice that 2.3.X alone is almost on 50% of the devices out there, so why not supporting them with our apps?

Does anyone know where to find code samples/tutorials on integrating google drive with an app written for 2.1+? I just want to sync some data (mostly the app's local database).

Comment: see this http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1257518

Comment: it says For earlier Android versions: Long-press an empty spot on your Home screen, and tap Widgets in the pop-up menu. Swipe left or right to find the Drive widget, tap it with your finger, and click Select.

Comment: Er... how does it help me integrating *my* apps with Drive?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Drive app for any device supporting Google Play Services, which is 2.2+.

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html